# How to Use Pointers to Structure to output？

Tags: c, struct

There are 3 students in a class,now I invoke `StuInfo(struct Student *p)` to get the information of these 3 students including IDs, names and their scores. I invoke `Rank(struct Student *p)` to rank their scores and output the best one's information. But,everytime, the output of `q->scores` is `0.00000` and I don't know why.

here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct Student 
{   
    int number;
    char name[20];
    double scores;
};
void StuInfo(struct Student *p);
void Rank(struct Student *p);
int main()
{   
    struct Student stus[3];
    struct Student *p;
    p=stus;
    StuInfo(p);
    Rank(p);
    return 0;
}
void StuInfo(struct Student *p) 
{
    printf("please enter the student'ID,name,scores："); 
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++) 
    {
        scanf("%d%s%f",&(p+i)->number,&(p+i)->name,&(p+i)->scores);     
    }       
}

void Rank(struct Student *p)
{
struct Student *q;
    q=p; 
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        if(q->scores<(p+i+1)->scores)
        {           
            q=p+i+1;
        }   
    }   
    printf("the best student's ID%d,name%s,score%f",q->number,q->name,q->scores);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple of tips I can suggest to make the code more readable and simple when dealing with pointer arithmetic.

1. You will need to fix your `scanf` format specifier this is why you keep reading `0.0000` for the score.  To fix it change the last `%f` to `%lf`.
2. You can simplify all this pointer and offset that you have here:
   `scanf("%d%s%f",&(p+i)->number,&(p+i)->name,&(p+i)->scores);`

    to just the following:
   `scanf("%d%s%lf", &p->number, &p->name, &p->scores);`
   `p++;`
   Since`p` is pointing to the size of a `struct Student` it will automatically increment to the next element when you do `p++`.  This is much easier to read and allows for less of a chance to have pointer arithmetic errors!!
3. You can clean up the last loop as well to avoid arithmetic errors and to simplify things a bit as follows:

   ```
   void Rank(struct Student *p)
   {
     struct Student *q;
     q = p;
     for (int i = 0; i<2; i++)
     {
       p++;
       if (q->scores < p->scores)
       {
         q = p;
       }
     }
     printf("the best student's ID: %d,name: %s,score: %f\n", q->number, q->name, q->scores)
   }
   ```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much! This helps me a lot! :)

Comment: No problem anytime! :)

Answer (score 2):

You have a little mistake in the scanf format, you need %lf for double not %f and the char array name don't need the address operator `&(p+i)->name` when using the pointer.
If you want to use the & address operator for the name then you have to point to the first element of the array like this `&(p+i)->name[0]`

I part from that your code should work

```
void StuInfo(struct Student *p)
{
    printf("please enter the student'ID,name,scores：");
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d%s%lf",&(p+i)->number,(p+i)->name,&(p+i)->scores);// here
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right!Now,the code works perfectly. I always make these little mistakes.Thank you so much!